# Flutter/Dart : How to get single colors from Colorgradient?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, widget, gradient

I am trying to build a Widget that changes it's background color from green to red over time, but in a fluid way. So similar to a gradient background:

[image]

But not as a fixed gradient, but rather a full green background at the beginning, and as the time counts down the background should slowly transition over to yellow, then orange, then red at the end.

I want the color to update every 10 miliseconds so it's not an abrupt change. I am handling the changing with a timer which calculates how much time has passed in relation to the start time and update the color accordingly.

Now - is there any way how I can get A concrete color from a gradient-like object? Like I could just extract the color of a gradient at a specific point (which is the fraction of time_passed/max_time) to use it as the full background?
Or should I actually use Colorcodes and just increase the value of the colorcode every 10ms? That seems not very graceful

Answer (score 3):

Ok I actually found two Solutions:

**1. Use Color.lerp(color a, color b, double p) function**
What this does is it creates a gradient between a and b, and return the color that exist on point p (value between 0 and 1) on that scale.
This is basically what I wanted, but there is a problem: It doesn't necessarily interpolate those two color with colors that you want to be inbetween, it's more of a brown-ish mix between those two.

**2. Install the rainbow_color package**
This was exactly what I needed, you can insert multiple custom colors, specify a range of values that you use (in my case 0.0 and 1.0, but it can also be integers), and it returns a gradient between only theese colors:

```
  var rb = Rainbow(
    spectrum: [
      Color(0xff1fff00),
      Color(0xffd0ff00),
      Color(0xffffaa00),
      Color(0xffffaa00),
      Color(0xffff6600)
    ],
    rangeStart: 1.0,
    rangeEnd: 0.0
  );

  return rb[remainingFraction];
```

[image]

Comment: If you're gonna lerp colors, it's better to use HSVColor() objects (easily mapped to and from Color() objects) because they provide a more natural lerping.